# How to use having clause within where clause condition?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to generate a MySQL query like the below, If I don't use **having clause**
and use plain where instead of it, then it will work (not with custom columns) but I need to use having so can use the new custom columns.

Is there any way we can do it? I'm using Laravel 8 with MySQL 8 on Ubuntu.

**Laravel Code**: Trying to run.

```
Booking::select('*', $booking_start_at, $booking_end_at)
    ->where('room_name', $data['room_name'])
    ->where(function ($q) use ($data) {
        $q->where(function ($query) use ($data) {
            $query->having('booking_start_at', '>', Carbon::parse($data['booking_start_date'] . $data['booking_start_time']))
                ->orHaving('booking_end_at', '<', Carbon::parse($data['booking_start_date'] . $data['booking_start_time']));

        })->where(function ($query) use ($data) {
            $query->having('booking_start_at', '>', Carbon::parse($data['booking_end_date'] . $data['booking_end_time']))
                ->orHaving('booking_end_at', '<', Carbon::parse($data['booking_end_date'] . $data['booking_end_time']));
        });
    });
```

**Desired SQL**: Not producing, and giving error.

```
select
    *,
    cast(
        concat(booking_start_date, 'T', booking_start_time) as datetime
    ) as booking_start_at,
    cast(
        concat(booking_end_date, 'T', booking_end_time) as datetime
    ) as booking_end_at
from
    `bookings`
where
    `room_name` = 1
    and (
        (
            having
                `booking_start_at` > '2022-06-20 06:00:00'
                or `booking_end_at` < '2022-06-20 06:00:00'
        )
        and (
            having
                `booking_start_at` > '2022-06-22 06:00:00'
                or `booking_end_at` < '2022-06-22 06:00:00'
        )
    )
```

Comment: The `HAVING` clause follows a `GROUP BY` clause, and is not used within a `WHERE` clause, which will error. I'm not near a PC at the moment to check, but replace those `having` and `orHaving` function calls with `where` should match the query that you want. (Without the nested `having`s in the wrong place)

Comment: I don't know, that's not my downvote.